# Get points from a Gdirections route

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude, google-maps-markers, gdirections

I'm trying to get a collection of points (latitude,longitude) between 2 adresses. The points needs to be on a valid tracfic route. I currently use Gdirections to create a route between 2 adresses. Is there a method to get somepoints allong this route? To me it seems impossible...

thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the returned polyline using [`GDirections.getPolyline()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#ReturningDirections) Then you can use [`GPolyline.getVertex(index:Number)`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GPolyline) to retrieve the vertex points along that route.